# How to get detailled infos after !dumpheap windbg command

Tags: windbg

I've executed the windbg command 
`!dumpheap -stat`  to get a dumpheap.
Now I want to get more information about a class type content.
How can I see more details for the  class type?

```
0:007> !do 00000000062782d0    
Free Object
Size:        566112(0x8a360) bytes
0:007> !do 000007ff00c88fc8        
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object
```

This does all not work to get more infos.
Is it possible to get IL Code also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net class is identified by Method Table, which lives in assembly metadata. Use `!dumpmt` to dump method table. E.g.:

`0:031> !dumpmt -md 71ad219c
EEClass:         716e3d94
Module:          716e1000
Name:            System.EventHandler
mdToken:         020000da
File:            C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
BaseSize:        0x20
ComponentSize:   0x0
Slots in VTable: 16
Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 2
MethodDesc Table
   Entry MethodDe    JIT Name
719c99d0 716e6a08 PreJIT System.Object.ToString()
719cf140 71766428 PreJIT System.MulticastDelegate.Equals(System.Object)
719e1440 71766484 PreJIT System.MulticastDelegate.GetHashCode()
719b1500 716e6a44 PreJIT System.Object.Finalize()
...`